# Find file with time range fileA and fileB

Tags: command-line, files, find, time

I am working on script where I will be receiving inputs as time and foldername,I need to find a file (snort.log.*) which is falling in that time range what my user enters (he will be seeing the alert file the bold time stamp  and entering that time for actual snort.log.** file which contains the details of attack and alert file contains the metadata only) 
here is directory sample

```
[jump1@widids01 snort-3]# ls -ltr | tail -6
-rwxr-x--- 1 snort snort    301731 Feb  2 18:18 snort.log.1517557015
-rwxr-x--- 1 snort snort   5720853 Feb  5 21:11 snort.log.1517563475
-rwxr-x--- 1 snort snort   3566073 Feb  7 16:00 snort.log.1517832965
-rwxr-x--- 1 snort snort     18999 Feb  7 20:46 snort.log.1518003111
-rwxr-x--- 1 snort snort  20705098 Feb 15 19:00 snort.log.1518004113
-rw------- 1 snort snort    357271 Feb 15 22:22 snort.log.1518688923
-rwxr-x--- 1 snort snort  50782147 Feb 15 22:22 alert
[jump1@widids01 snort-3]# tail -3 alert
02/15-18:22:02.204655   [1:2403380:38412] ET CINS Active Threat Intelligence Poor Reputation IP TCP group 41  [Classification: Misc Attack] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 
02/15-22:22:03.335107   [1:2403408:38412] ET CINS Active Threat Intelligence Poor Reputation IP TCP group 55  [Classification: Misc Attack] [Priority: 2] {TCP} 
02/15-22:22:03.335107   [1:2403408:38412] ET CINS Active Threat Intelligence Poor Reputation IP TCP group 55  [Classification: Misc Attack] [Priority: 2] {TCP}
```

I am facing the issues here the `snort.log.[epoch]` i.e `[epoch]` is file generated time, so if user enters

testcase1:

```
time:2015-02-15-22:28:02
```

how to give him the matching `snort.log.file` for where the attack data contains

testcase2:

```
time:2015-02-15-18:22:02
```

how to give him the matching `snort.log.file` for where the attack data contains

I tried with `find . -newermt "2018-02-15 18:38:00" ! -newermt "2018-02-15 18:39:00"` I am not getting proper output.

Comment: Presumably you want the *oldest* file whose modification time is newer than the given timestamp? I don't think `find` on its own can provide that.

Comment: Thankq.. Any Ideas or suggestions I can take from there..

Comment: You can use `date` to parse timestamps with known formats, say to convert them to Unix time.

Comment: What does the timestamp the user enters represent? Is it the log file's modification time, is it the last part of the log file's filename or is it actually a time range (time stamp entered till now?) from which the oldest/newest log should be matched? Please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: @dessert the user blindly pass a date from alert file(please check the bold ones) I need to take that input and see where that time pcap data is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an input like this:

```bsh
time="time:2015-02-15-18:22:02"
```

Then you can convert it to a Unix timestamp (seconds since epoch) and save it in variable `timestamp` with:

```bsh
time=$(date -d$(<<<"$time" sed 's/time:\(.*\)-/\1T/') +%s)
```

I use `sed` here to get rid of the `time:` prefix and change the colon between date and time to `T` ([ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)), `date` is then used to convert the timestamp to seconds since epoch.

Depending on what this timestamp represents you can then use `find` to output the log's filename:

- if the filename already contains the timestamp, you can use `snort.log.$time` directly
- if it's the file's modification time:

  ```bsh
  find . -type f -name "*snort.log.*" -newermt @$(($time-1)) ! -newermt @$time
  ```

  This will find every log file with a modification time between `time` - 1 second and `time`.
- if you need to find the oldest log file from after the given timestamp, you can use `sort` and `head`:

  ```bsh
  find . -type f -name "*snort.log.*" -newermt @$(($time-1)) -print0 | sort -z | head -zn1
  ```
- if you need to find the log file that (in any way) *contains* the given timestamp, use `grep`:

  ```bsh
  grep -l $time *
  ```

  If you have a lot of long log files maybe combine this with `find` and/or `parallel` to make it faster, e.g.:

  ```bsh
  find . -type f -name "*snort.log.*" -newermt @$(($time-1)) -exec grep -l $time {} +
  ```